# KDE: Unknown protocol 'unityhub' even though unityhub does exist

Tags: linux, kde, kde-plasma-5, xdg

I'm using KDE Neon and have installed Unity Hub via it's AppImage and integrated it with my system.

The problem is when I tried to install Unity Editor via UnityHub button on this Download Archive page, it will throw an error, saying:
`Unable to create io-slave. klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'unityhub'`

The link that I tried to click is
`unityhub://2019.4.0f1/0af376155913`

In UnityHub AppImage .desktop shortcut, the mimetype unityhub does exist:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Unity Hub (2.3.2)
Exec=/home/risal/Applications/UnityHub_00000000000000000000000000000000.AppImage
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=appimagekit_749a56827cf394434a5ee3f8dc8e0986_unityhub
StartupWMClass=Unity Hub
X-AppImage-Version=2.3.2
Comment=The Official Unity Hub
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/unityhub;
Categories=Development;

TryExec=/home/risal/Applications/UnityHub_00000000000000000000000000000000.AppImage
X-AppImage-Old-Icon=unityhub
X-AppImage-Old-Name=Unity Hub
X-AppImage-Identifier=749a56827cf394434a5ee3f8dc8e0986
Actions=Remove;
X-AppImageLauncher-Version=

[Desktop Action Remove]
Name=Remove AppImage from system
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/appimagelauncher/remove "/home/risal/Applications/UnityHub_00000000000000000000000000000000.AppImage"
```

Because of this problem I can only install Unity Editor via UnityHub directly, with only very limited versions available. Please Help.

```
Unity Hub version: 2.3.2
Operating System: KDE neon 5.19
KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.72.0
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-42-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 12 × AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650G with Radeon Graphics
Memory: 14,5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: llvmpipe
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when upgrading an older UnityHub/Unity install.  Even after creating the mimtypes I would get the error you describe.

I haven't found a fix for the mimetypes error, **but here's a workaround** to install the latest version:  Just go to a terminal and run UnityHub with the URL directly.  ex:  '/opt/Unity/UnityHub.AppImage unityhub://2020.1.0b16/70ea0f8c4a3c'

Comment: This also works for UnityHub login. When login ended up with a blank page, I grabbed the failed URL from the Firefox's Inspector page (Console).